# WSO2 EI 6.2.0 ESB debugging mediation doesn't open Synapse debug ports

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Everywhere in documentation is written, the ESB mediation debugger can be run by the command `.\integrator.bat --run -Desb.debug=true`. However, the property doesn't trigger the synapse debugging ports and the *README* doesn't say a word about the property. It seems the command has changed.

Is there any possibility to run ESB Mediation Debugger in Developer Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but when i looked at the .bat file i realized this works

```
    .\integrator.bat --debug 5005
```

(5005) being the port number

Edit:

I realised this might not be the debug mode you are looking for, it seems that integrator.bat is not passing your arguments along. I found this line

```
    set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
```

and added -Desb.debug=true to it there